# What did Stitch say when he laughed after the arrival?

Tags: dialogue, lilo-and-stitch

What did Stitch say when he laughed after the arrival in this scene:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language Stitch speaks is [Tantalog](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Tantalog_language). It is a combination of Hawaiian, Chinese and Chezcreekian.

I think he is saying something along the line of "I came, I saw, and I conquered."
I don't know the exact meaning, but here are some dictionaries:

http://disneydestiny.proboards.com/thread/202/stitch-language
https://cavemanboo.deviantart.com/art/Stitch-s-Vocabulary-290229838

Answer (score 3):

[This transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=lilo-and-stitch) says it's just alien language

> Maybe send me an angel...
>   the nicest angel you have.
>   (flames roaring)
>   (shouting in alien language)
>   (laughing maniacally)

According to the [quotes on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0275847/quotes/qt0300649)

> **Stitch**: Poocha Chubugga Oom Chickee! Ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha!

The alien language is used many times in the movie, but it's never translated. Most times we can guess the meaning by the situation or other people's reaction.

I have looked online, where people have made translations for the language, called Tantalog, but I couldn't find anything for this phrase or any of the words.

Comment: nice find on the imdb quotes! Likewise, poked around looking for the actual screenplay but couldn't find one anywhere.

Comment: I don't know what answer I realy want to accept. You have the transcription, that was very nice! But Boondoggle's answer have a  little more meaning information (I know, just conjectures)....

Comment: Just a remark: Google Translator said it's from `Hindi` language and suggest `Pushcha Chubaggaam Chumki` or `पुछा चुबुग्गा ूम चिक्की`. I have no idea of the meaning and so sorry if it is a bad language.